# I can't see any incoming requests in Google Cloud Endpoint console

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to configure Google Cloud Endpoint in front of Cloud Run. I decided to use the OpenAPI 2.0 standard so I can use Python 3.6.5 as a language to develop my backend.

I followed this guide https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run.
I've been able to set up a custom domain name for my Cloud Endpoints like api.example.com and I'm able to make API calls to my endpoints.

The only problem is that I can't see any incoming requests and any logs in my Cloud Endpoints console. I can only see them in the Cloud Run console.

How is possible? What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to create enable my Flask app to support another endpoint and I didn't update the openapi.yaml file with the new endpoint. My service is giving me answers if I make API calls to the new endpoints.

How is possible if I didn't update that file?

I'm starting to think that I didn't configure well the Cloud Endpoint and I'm making API calls directly to my Cloud Run service.

Comment: It seems like that you were calling your Cloud Run service directly.  By default, api-key is required to call ESP unless you specifically disable it.  Try to call it without api-key to see if it go through.  If the request go to ESP (Cloud endpoint proxy), it will fail without api-key.

Comment: I didn't disable it and if I call the endpoint, the request doesn't fail. I reviewed the guide and I did all the steps. How's possible?